# Angular 2 pass a parameter that's on the submit button

Tags: angular, typescript

For various reasons I have 2 submit buttons in a form. But I need to be able to work out which submit button was clicked on. So far I am using the below, but how could I add a different parameter on each submit button?

```
<button type="submit" [disabled]="!f.valid">Approve</button>
```

Perhaps I could add a data tag to the button and pass the event to the ngSubmit function somehow?

Comment: why two submit buttons ? what if the user uses the `Enter` key in a text input ?

Comment: @n00dl3 hmm you have a very very good point. Thanks I'll revise this.